# Custom pipeline in Biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have requirement in BizTalk 2010 where i am receiving txt file of size 80kb + and I need to convert them into txt files with smaller size e.g 8 kb so I will have 10 files out of one 80kb file,
What's the best way to approach this requirement? Do i  need to create custom pipeline?

All suggestions are welcome :).

Comment: Do the files have to be correlated or can the 10 files be processed out of order?

Comment: Is the 80k file a flat file and does it have a header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a custom pipeline with a custom disassemble component is what you need. Don't forget to copy the original message context to new messages. Create additional context properties if you need them (part number for example).